# How do i stop a dependency from re-rendering infinite times in a useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, filtering, onload, multi-select

I have a react-select multiselect component which is required to have preselected values based on the user role. The react-select component is used to filter data in a react-table.

I have 2 user roles - Dev and tester.
If it the dev, I need to have open and Reopened issues to be filtered on load
If it is a tester, I need to have resolved issues on load

This is a part of the code that i am using to achieve preselected

```
async function loadInfo() {
    const body = {
        project_id: projDetails.id,
    };

    const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: apilist.dropdownData,
        data: body,
    })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    if (response) {
        const getData = response.data.data;
        // console.log("IsGeneralInfo:", getData)
        setGeneralInfo(getData);

        let filteredenv = getData.status.filter((item) => item.id == 8 || item.id == 6)
        let envfiltered = filteredenv.map((k) => {
            return ({ label: k.values, value: k.values });
        })

        // console.log("envfilter", envfiltered);
        // handleMultiStatusFilter(envfiltered);
    }
}    

// const {current:myArray}=useRef([{ label: 'Closed', value: 'Closed' }])
useEffect(() => {
    if(envfilter){
        let myArray=[{ label: 'Closed', value: 'Closed' },{ label: 'Reopen', value: 'Reopen' }];
        handleMultiStatusFilter(myArray);        
    }
}, [selectedOptions])    

const handleStatusFilter = (e) => {
    setFilterValue(e);
    if (e.length > 0) {
        dispatch(filterByValue({ type: e, viewIssue: viewIssue, }))
    }
    else {
        dispatch(showAllStatus({ type: 'All', viewIssue: viewIssue, }))
    }
}

const handleMultiStatusFilter = (e) => {
    setFiltered([])
    let arr = []
    e.map((data) => {
        setFiltered(prevState => [...prevState, data.value]);
        arr.push(data.value);
    })
    setSelectedOptions(e)
    handleStatusFilter(arr)
}
```

This is a part of the redux code used for filtering

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
        // Add reducers for additional action types here, and handle loading state as needed
        builder.addCase(fetchIssueList.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            // Add user to the state array
            state.issuesList = {
                status: 'idle',
                data: action.payload.data.data !== undefined ? action.payload.data.data : [],
                dataContainer: action.payload.data.data !== undefined ? action.payload.data.data : [],
                no_of_records: action.payload.data.data !== undefined ? action.payload.data.data.length : 0,
                error: {}
            }
        })
```

The code works fine with the filtering once i login, but the rerendering keeps going to infinite loop

Is there any way i could stop the infinite rerendering of code and have the filtering happen on load of the screen?

Comment: The dependency you have added changes each time as it set in the function ....

Comment: You are watching changes to `selectedOptions` and then triggering changes to `selectedOptions`. Hence the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

while working with dependencies in useEffect, try to use the most primitive part you can find. no complex objects, as they change way too fast.
for example: use the length of an array not the array itself.
even though for arrays it's mostly safe to use itself.

Answer (score 0):

sorry. correction: for arrays it's not safe either. complex objects are compared by reference not by value. for that you need primitive types like number, string or boolean.